# 256-bit integer to string

Tags: c, string, integer

I need to convert a 256-bit integer that is represented as a array of 32-bit integer to string in *decimal* representation.

```
typedef struct {
    uint32_t x[8];
} Uint256;
```

I can't add dependencies to the project so I cannot use additional libraries.
Is there a way to achieve that *efficiently*?

Comment: The *simplest* approach is to iteratively divide by 10 and take the remainder each time.  If you try that, is it fast *enough*?

Comment: lookup table of 8 bit representation that returns the string format of the value

Comment: Also, to clarify, you want to get the **decimal representation of this 256-bit value**, is that correct?  (As opposed to say, a hex representation, or the representation of the individual components, or something like that.)

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth How do you divide such a number by 10 and take the remainder?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Exactly, edit to include this. Also, how I can divide a number represented as this? (I only implemented addition, multiplication and bitwise operations)

Comment: @Gerhardh - Think of it like how you probably did long division at school.  Divide each digit (in this case, each 32-bit component) by 10, starting from the most-significant.  The remainder is combined with the next digit (which in this case is relatively easy if you have 64-bit integers available), and so on.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I would assume this is the main part of the question. ;)

Comment: Have u got an answer ?